# Error when calling the Anomaly Detection API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, anomaly-detection

I've been messing with the [Anomaly Detection API](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-anomaly-finder) as part of the Microsoft Cognitive Services Labs. However, when I try to POST data to get a response, it always comes back as

```
400: TypeError('string indices must be integers'
```

Thinking this is an issue with the format of the data I'm giving it, I double check it with what they have as a [sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftAnomalyDetection/python-sample/blob/master/sample.json):

```
{
  "Period": 7,
  "Points": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-03-01T00:00:00Z",
      "Value": 32858923
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-03-02T00:00:00Z",
      "Value": 29615278
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-03-03T00:00:00Z",
      "Value": 22839355
    },
  ]
}
```

And here is some of the data that I'm sending to it that returns the error:

```
{  
  "Period": 1,
  "Points":[  
    {  
      "Timestamp": "1962-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "Value": 589
    },
    {  
      "Timestamp": "1962-02-01T00:00:00Z",
      "Value": 561
    },
    {  
      "Timestamp": "1962-03-01T00:00:00Z",
      "Value": 640
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Python to call the API with the `requests` package:

```
request = json.dumps(output)
config = json.load(open("config.json"))
url = "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/anomalyfinder/v1.0/anomalydetection"
headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": config["apiKey"]}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=request)
```

The `output` object is a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'Period': 1,
 'Points': [{'Timestamp': '1962-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'Value': 589},
  {'Timestamp': '1962-02-01T00:00:00Z', 'Value': 561},
  {'Timestamp': '1962-03-01T00:00:00Z', 'Value': 640}]}
```

Which was derived from the [monthly milk production data set](https://datamarket.com/data/set/22ox/monthly-milk-production-pounds-per-cow-jan-62-dec-75#!ds=22ox&display=line).

Is there something wrong with my data that I'm missing to cause it to return back that error?

Comment: the only differences I can see is that they have a single whitespace after each colon and a trailing comma after last entry in list

Comment: @chris Actually, I ran the JSON from my data against a JSON formatter so I can have it formatted for this question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Please add details on how you are calling the API (real implementation)

Comment: Apologies @NicolasR, updated to add how the API is getting called.

Comment: No problem, but add really everything (like how you populate your `request` variable)

Comment: @NicolasR added more details to the question. Thanks!